# React: I can't get updated state values in the onScroll function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Task:** I am trying to implement dynamic loading of content when scrolling for a reaction.
I have an `onScroll` function to listen for a scroll event, which switches the isFetching variable to true when the page is scrolled all the way down. When `isFetching === true`, the code from `useEffect` is executed and the content is loaded.
Everything works as it should, but I need to add another condition to `onScroll`, which is triggered while the amount of loaded data is < the total amount of data.

**Problem:** I have variables `schoolResults` and `schoolResultsCount`, which contain the number of loaded data and the total amount of data, but they are not updated when scrolling, they are always 0 when scrolling.
I understand that I can transfer the function to `useEffect` or use a condition in `useEffect` and everything will work as I need. But I don't understand why the updated values of external variables are not available in the function?

Thank you for your help!

```
export default function Results(props: Props) {
   const location = useLocation();

   const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
   const [isFetching, setFetching] = useState<boolean>(false);
   const [schoolResults, setSchoolResults] = useState<SchoolEvent[]>([]);
   const [schoolResultsCount, setSchoolResultsCount] = useState<number>(0);
   const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(1);

   const { school } = props;
   const { id: schoolId } = school;


   useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);

      const promises = [
         getSchoolEvents(schoolId, getFilterForAllSchoolResults()),
         getSchoolEventsCount(schoolId, getFilterForAllSchoolResults())
      ];

      Promise.all(promises).then(([events, eventsCountObj]) => {
         setSchoolResults(events);
         setSchoolResultsCount(eventsCountObj.count);
         setLoading(false);
      });
   }, [location.search]);

   useEffect(() => {
      if (isFetching) {

         const queryFilter = {
            ...getFilterForAllSchoolResults(),
            skip: currentPage * LIMIT
         };

         getSchoolEvents(schoolId, queryFilter)
            .then((events) => {
               setSchoolResults([...schoolResults, ...events]);
               setCurrentPage(prevState => prevState + 1);
            })
            .finally(() => setFetching(false));
      }
   }, [isFetching]);

   useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

      return function () {
         document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
      }
   }, []);

   const onScroll = (event: Event) => {
      const { target } = event;

      const scrollHeight = propz.get(target, ['documentElement', 'scrollHeight']);
      const scrollTop = propz.get(target, ['documentElement', 'scrollTop']);
      const windowInnerHeight = window.innerHeight;

      const isBottomOfPage = scrollHeight - (scrollTop + windowInnerHeight) < 100;

      // console.log('schoolResults', schoolResults.length); //The value is 0. Not updated. Why?
      // console.log('schoolResultsCount', schoolResultsCount); // The value is 0. Not updated. Why?

      if (isBottomOfPage /*&& schoolResults.length > schoolResultsCount*/) {
         setFetching(true);
      };
   };

   if (isLoading) {
      return <Loader />;
   }

   return (//Some JSX)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) problem.

You have a `useEffect` with no dependencies, that attaches the `onScroll` handler to the `scroll` event when the component mounts (and removes it when the component unmounts). Because of the empty dependency array, this function is the same for the lifetime of the component.

And that's the problem, because the `onScroll` that's in scope on that first render is one that references an empty array as its `schoolResults`, because that's what the `const schoolResults` holds on that first render. Yes it will have a different value on subsequent renders, but those are forever inaccessible to the `onScroll` event handler that's being used.

The best solution likely depends on details of your component that you haven't given. The simplest is to replace the state with a ref, since refs, unlike state variables, maintain the same identity between renders, with only their `current` property updating (mutating). So you can replace

```
const [schoolResults, setSchoolResults] = useState<SchoolEvent[]>([]);
```

with

```
const schoolResults = useRef<SchoolEvent[]>([]);
```

and replace all calls to `setSchoolResults(someValue)` to `schoolResults.current = someValue`. (And likewise where you reference `schoolResults` to get its value, replace that by `schoolResults.current`.) This will solve the stale closure problem. (And you'll have to do this with each of the relevant state variables.)

However the disadvantage of refs as opposed to state is that updating a ref does NOT cause a rerender, unlike state updates. So if anything in your Component's rendered JSX output uses `isLoading`, this won't work as expected.

So in that case you'll have to use another solution, which involves being honest about the fact that your state is updating so you need to update the event handler function to one which uses the correct value. There are only a few steps though:

First, wrap the event handler in `useCallback`, and put all the relevant state values you're referencing in its dependency array:

```
const onScroll = useCallback(() => { /* your function goes here */, [schoolResults, schoolResultsCount, /* you possibly need other dependencies here, that are used inside your function */]};
```

Then add `onScroll` as a dependency to the `useEffect` which adds the scroll handler:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

  return function () {
     document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }
}, [onScroll]);
```

This should then work as you expect, by ensuring the scroll handler always holds up-to-date values of your state variables.